# Disable inputs from a modal on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable inputs from a modal when clicking on a "edit" button.
I was trying something like this:

```js
function DisableFields() {
  $("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

function EditFields() {
  if ($("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled')) {
    $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main" onload="DisableFields();">
  <input class="formInput" type="text" value="Doritos">
  <button type="button" onclick="EditFields();">Edit</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        DisableFields();
    })

    function DisableFields() {
        $("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

    function EditFields() {
        if ($("input").attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
            $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $("input").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
```

html tag 'main' does not support 'onload' event.